# Multiple domains for webshop

Tags: seo, e-commerce, ranking, multiple-domains, webshop

I'm looking to use multiple domains for my webshop and I'm wondering how it will affect SEO and search engine ranking.

Currently I have a generic name as a webshop, let us call it www.mysmallshop.com. I sell many different things. I recently acquired a new domain called www.clothing.com.

Now if my webshop have these categories; Shoes, Clothes, Accessories, Jackets and I change my webshop so that all products under the category Clothes will have the URL www.clothing.com/productname instead of www.mysmallshop.com/clothing/productname, would it break any SEO and search engine ranking? And is it a good idea to use the domain in such a way or am I better off doing what all other SEO sharks does and "make a fake blog" and link back to my original store? Any ideas or input?

Content duplication is not an issue, will use canonical URLs or plain redirect to ensure that URLs are consistent. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. I suggest trying at [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would... tell the engines that your "not so generic" webshopname is permatly moved (and by this not decreasing/influencing SEO score)

by a mod_rewrite (if apache is involved) by this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.?)slave-webshop.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mainwebshop.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The other domain is not in use. But what you're saying is that it is not a good idea?

Comment: no, you can always buy more than one domain (but its rather bad for customer recognition having more than one "name" for a website). And using the permanetly moved redirect is the only one I know not beeing downgraded by crawlers/search engines.